# Inexplicable “The system cannot find the drive specified.” How to solve it?

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file

I'm creating a Batch file and it was working OK, then, suddenly, it started throwing an error that's making me scratch my head and reach the limit of my ignorance.

I reduced the Batch file to the bare minimum to replicate the error in my machine:

```bash
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "exclFolder=%UserProfile%\OneDrive\"

:: Lists all the common image files in the HD

for /R %%f IN (*.jpeg;*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif;*.png;*.ico;*.webp) DO (
    
    :: Ignores any file in the OneDrive folder
    
    set "fileName=%%~nxf"
    echo %%f | findstr /i /c:"!exclFolder!" > nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
         echo %%f
        )
    )
```

This is a sample of the execution on my machine:

```bash
>Test.bat
The system cannot find the drive specified.
C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\kgysoft.corelibraries\7.1.0\Icon64.png

The system cannot find the drive specified.
C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\kgysoft.drawing\7.2.0\Icon64.png

The system cannot find the drive specified.
C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\kgysoft.drawing.core\7.2.0\Icon64.png
```

I thought this would be a simple thing to do, but this strange error has thrown a lot of sand in my mental gears.

Comment: Does “%UserProfile%” have a space in it when you navigate to it with File Explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
@echo off && SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd /d "%~dp0" || exit /b 

set "_ExclFolder=\%UserName%\OneDrive\"

for /r %%f in (*.jpeg;*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif;*.png;*.ico;*.webp)do =;(
     set "_FileName=%%~nxf"
     echo/"%%~f" | findstr /ic:"!_ExclFolder!" >nul || echo/"%%~f"
    );=

endlocal
```

---

> *Inexplicable `“The system cannot find the drive specified.”`*
> *How to solve it?*
> -***`echo "I have no idea!" | findstr "....`***
>
> ```
> echo Double quotes do not go on vacation, you can use them all year round
> echo "%%~f" | ...
> ```
>
> If a file **name* contains a character that does not belong to the alphanumeric and may be part of the group of special characters, then some breakage may occur, confusing the command interpreter and making it look for a file that it cannot find, or your bat starts in a different location from where it should operate, and not having files in the searched extensions, it returns to with coherences `The system cannot find the drive specified.`

---

I would do it differently...

---

```bash
@echo off

cd /d "%~dp0" || exit /b 
set "_aVoid=.*\\OneDrive\\.*"
set "_eXt=*.jpeg *.jpg *.bmp *.gif *.png *.ico *.webp"

for /f usebackq^delims^= %%i in =;(
   `where /r .\ %_eXt% ^| findstr /Vi %_aVoid%
   `);= do =;(
      set "_fName=%%~nxi"
      set "_fullPath=%%~fi"
      call echo/"%%_fullPath%%" "%%_fName%%"
    );=
```

---

**1.** Enter the folder where you have the batch with **`cd /d "%~dp0"`** and if it is not the `\working\folder`, then point to the full path:

```bash
cd /d "D:\The\Full\Path\Folder"
```

---

**2.** Replace `For /R` with `For /F`

```bash
for /f `...  %%f in (`commmad ^| findsrt ...
```

---

**3.** Use `Where /Recursive` (always lists **files** avoiding **\folders**)

```bash
for /f ...(` Where /r .\ *.jpeg *.jpg *.bmp *.gif *.png *.ico *.webp ^| ...
```

---

**4.** Brings your `findstr /Avoid String in` loop `(command)`

```bash
for /f ...(` ... ^| findstr /vi .*\\%UserName%\\OneDrive\\.*
```

---

**5.** UsUse the loop outputs wherever you need and however you want

```bash
`);= do set "_fName=%%~nxf" && call echo/"%%_fName%%"
```

---

```bash
@echo off

cd /d "%~dp0" || exit /b 
set "_aVoid=.*\\OneDrive\\.*"
set "_eXt=*.jpeg *.jpg *.bmp *.gif *.png *.ico *.webp"

for /f usebackq^delims^= %%i in =;(`where /r .\ %_eXt% ^| findstr /vi %_aVoid%
   `);= do set "_fName=%%~nxi" & set "_fullPath=%%~fi" && call echo/"%%_fullPath%%" "%%_fName%%"
```

---

---

## Additional resources:

- [`Cd` | `ChDir`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [`FindSTR /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

  - [`For /F commands`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [Escape Characters](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

---

Comment: You seem to be quoting something in the paragraph that goes  "If a file contains a character that". What?

Comment: No, that's not what I'm asking. You have used quote formatting there, and the first part is definitely quoted from the question, but what is the rest of the quote block quoting? Some documentation? A blog? Another answer? If so, please make it clear and provide attribution to whatever source you're using

Comment: I have no idea what it is you're trying to say in that comment, half of it makes no sense to me. In any case, if you're quoting this user then provide the attribution at the place you're quoting, and make it clear that it's from that user, since the linked question has multiple answers. A link to the question at the bottom of the answer after a dozen other links without any clarification isn't sufficient.

Comment: And if you're not quoting anything, then please don't misuse quote formatting for emphasis.

Comment: @muru Thank you!  I see that the idea is not to help, could you do it directly without confusing me.